# Why multiprocessing.Process works with inner functions but multiprocessing.Pool does not?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's suppose that I have an inner function:

```
def higher(x):
    def lower(y):
        print(x + y)
    return lower
h = higher(10)
```

I can successfully run this function on a separate process

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=h, args=(20,))
p.start()
```

```
30
```

But when I try to run it on a pool of processes I get a pickle error:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = higher(10)
    p = Pool(processes=10)
    p.map(h, [1, 2, 3])
```

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'higher.<locals>.lower'
```

I am wondering why there is this difference of behavior between Process and Pool that I thought to be just a set of processes. Honestly I thought that also the version with Process would have raised the same pickle error.
(I noticed that the same happens with lambda functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Process

`multiprocessing.Process` spawns a subprocess that you have to manage, `join()`, `terminate()`, etc. It reinitializes all imports and function definitions that are defined outside of the `if __name__ =='__main__'` block.

So in the case of `Process`, the function `higher()` is defined within the subprocess's scope.

#### Pool

`Pool` on the otherhand uses worker processes which receive tasks and submit answers via queues, which require serialization (pickling), [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d18e5dae914b1db49b25ed7729c07a535d1f0c52/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L97).

So in the case of `Pool`, the function `higher()` is being passed to the worker process via a queue. This throws an error with inner and lambda functions, because they are not serializable.

#### Additional note:

`multiprocessing` using `pickle` for serialization. The `dill` library should be able to serialize inner and lambda functions, unlike `pickle`.